What the Ganesha/Mudgala Puranas mention about Ganesha's eight forms?
I am aware of Ganesha's eight forms, Vaktratunda, Ekadanta, Lambodara, Mahodara, Gajanana, Vikata, Vighnaraja and Dhurmavarna and they are incarnated to save everyone from the demons that embodies several sins.
But, does them mention in Ganesha and/or Mudgala Purana?

Mudgala Purana does have a mention of Ganesha's 8 forms.

@অনু Ok. Can you pls answer about that?
